# Android error "The application icon is not valid. Use a 48x48 PNG file." in google play

Tags: android, google-play

hello I tried to upload an update of my app to Google Play and I found this error, looking on it in google I found multiple solutions but none seem to work.

-I looking for "/n" on my strings.xml.

-Icon files on drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi and drawable folders have the correct size. Respectively 72x72, 48x48, 36x36 and 48x48 .png files.

-In my manifest i dont have android:debuggable label.

I stick my manifest in case anyone sees any errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="es.gleb" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="201204041800">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                 android:label="@string/app_name" 
                 android:name="es.gleb.GlebApplication"
                 >

        <activity android:name="es.gleb.ui.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="es.gleb.ui.EventsListActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="es.gleb.ui.EventActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>     

        <activity android:name="es.gleb.ui.LocationsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="es.gleb.ui.ExecutionActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="es.gleb.ui.ExecutionsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="es.gleb.ui.OptionsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>     

        <activity android:name="es.gleb.ui.StationsListActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>             

        <activity android:name="es.gleb.ui.WebViewActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>             

        <service android:name="es.gleb.ui.ForegroundService" />

        <!--  android:process=":remote"-->
        <provider android:name="es.gleb.provider.ZenerLanProvider" 
            android:authorities="es.gleb.provider.ZenerLanProvider">
        </provider>

        <receiver android:name="es.gleb.poller.OnAlarmReceiver"  />

        <service android:name="es.gleb.poller.PollerService"  />

        <service android:name="es.gleb.service.QueueService"/>

        <receiver android:name="es.gleb.poller.OnBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: did you change the version number?

Comment: Yes i change the version number..

Comment: @Chirag Raval the logo shown in google play is a high resolution icon 512 x 512.. I'm desperate..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for several answers... they were deleted, but i want to say about solution in my case: "\n" at the end of app_name string caused this problem.